# Array intersection as aggregate function for group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE person
AS
  SELECT name, preferences
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 'John', ARRAY['pizza', 'meat'] ),
    ( 'John', ARRAY['pizza', 'spaghetti'] ),
    ( 'Bill', ARRAY['lettuce', 'pizza'] ),
    ( 'Bill', ARRAY['tomatoes'] )
  ) AS t(name, preferences);
```

I want to `group by person` with `intersect(preferences)` as aggregate function. So I want the following output:

```
person | preferences
-------------------------------
John   | ['pizza']
Bill   | []
```

How should this be done in SQL? I guess I need to do something like the following, but what does the `X` function look like?

```
SELECT    person.name, array_agg(X)
FROM      person
LEFT JOIN unnest(preferences) preferences
ON        true
GROUP BY  name
```

Comment: probably join unnest(preferences) ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I think that's a good idea, but how can I intersect with that join (and apply `array_agg` afterwards)?

Comment: There is chance that array have duplicate values ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze No, the array does not contain duplicates and no `null`s.

Comment: Also important, the array can be empty, so I guess to need to `left join` the `unnest(preferences)`.

Comment: that null changes the logic to outer join, but then intersect looses sense :)

Comment: Exactly :) Still puzzling my head around this.

Comment: Is your requested output correct? If the rows are grouped by person, then I would think Bill's array_agg(preferences) would be ['tomatoes']. If there was NO group by on the select, then array_agg(preferences) = [].

Comment: My desired output is correct. I need the intersection of the preferences.

Comment: Quite right, sorry. For some reason I got it into my head that John had three rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FILTER` with `ARRAY_AGG`

```
SELECT name, array_agg(pref) FILTER (WHERE namepref = total)
FROM (
  SELECT name, pref, t1.count AS total, count(*) AS namepref
  FROM (
    SELECT name, preferences, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
    FROM person
  ) AS t1
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(preferences) AS pref
  GROUP BY name, total, pref
) AS t2
GROUP BY name;
```

Here is one way to do it using the `ARRAY` constructor and `DISTINCT`.

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT name, pref, t1.count AS total, count(*) AS namepref
  FROM (
    SELECT name, preferences, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
    FROM person
  ) AS t1
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(preferences) AS pref
  GROUP BY name, total, pref
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  name,
  ARRAY(SELECT pref FROM t AS t2 WHERE total=namepref AND t.name = t2.name)
FROM t;
```

Comment: That will *not* calculate the intersection of the arrays, but produce an array that contains all preferences that occur more than once. Try with these three records: `('Paul', ARRAY['pizza', 'meat'])`, `('Paul', ARRAY['pizza', 'salad'])` and `('Paul', ARRAY['salad', 'beer'])`. The result should be empty, but your query will produce `{pizza,salad}`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe fixed.

Comment: That will work unless there are arrays that contain the same value more than once.

Answer (score 5):

You could create your own aggregate function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arr_sec_agg_f(anyarray, anyarray) RETURNS anyarray
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
   'SELECT CASE
              WHEN $1 IS NULL
              THEN $2
              WHEN $2 IS NULL
              THEN $1
              ELSE array_agg(x)
           END
    FROM (SELECT x FROM unnest($1) a(x)
          INTERSECT
          SELECT x FROM unnest($2) a(x)
         ) q';

CREATE AGGREGATE arr_sec_agg(anyarray) (
   SFUNC = arr_sec_agg_f(anyarray, anyarray),
   STYPE = anyarray
);

SELECT name, arr_sec_agg(preferences)
FROM person
GROUP BY name;

┌──────┬─────────────┐
│ name │ arr_sec_agg │
├──────┼─────────────┤
│ John │ {pizza}     │
│ Bill │             │
└──────┴─────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Comment: That's neat, I did not know that is possible. I will continue searching for a query, as I cannot change the schema currently. What should I do in this case? Accept this question and ask the question again with note that I cannot create my own function, and therefore am looking for a plain query?

Comment: You got two other answers already, one of which you accepted as correct, so why don't you go with these?

Answer (score 1):

If writing a custom aggregate (like @LaurenzAlbe provided) is not an option for you, you can *usually* enroll the same logic in a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with recursive cte(name, pref_intersect, pref_prev, iteration) as (
    select   name,
             min(preferences),
             min(preferences),
             0
    from     your_table
    group by name
  union all
    select   name,
             array(select e from unnest(pref_intersect) e
                   intersect
                   select e from unnest(pref_next) e),
             pref_next,
             iteration + 1
    from     cte,
    lateral  (select   your_table.preferences pref_next
              from     your_table
              where    your_table.name        = cte.name
              and      your_table.preferences > cte.pref_prev
              order by your_table.preferences
              limit    1) n
)
select   distinct on (name) name, pref_intersect
from     cte
order by name, iteration desc
```

http://rextester.com/ZQMGW66052

The main idea here is to find an ordering in which you can "walk" through your rows. I used the natural ordering of the `preferences` array (because not much of your columns are being showed). Ideally, this ordering should happen on (a) unique field(s) (preferably on the primary key), but here, because duplications in the `preferences` column does not influence the result of the intersection, it is good enough.